# Create PowerPoint presentation from Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a PP slideshow from an Excel spreadsheet.  I have this VBA module:

```
     Sub CreatePowerPointQuestions()
    Dim newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim Question As String
    Dim Options As String
    Dim Answer As String
    Dim limit As Integer

    limit = 3
    On Error Resume Next
Set newPowerPoint = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If newPowerPoint Is Nothing Then
    Set newPowerPoint = New PowerPoint.Application
End If

   'Make a presentation in PowerPoint
  If newPowerPoint.Presentations.Count = 0 Then
    newPowerPoint.Presentations.Add
  End If

'Show the PowerPoint
newPowerPoint.Visible = True
'Select worksheet and cells activate
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

'Loop through each question
For i = 1 To limit

'Add a new slide where we will paste the Question and Options:
    newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, 3
    newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    Set activeSlide = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)

'Set the variables to the cells
    Question = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
    Options = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
    Answer = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value


    activeSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Question
    activeSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Options

    activeSlide.Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Answer

Next


Set activeSlide = Nothing
Set newPowerPoint = Nothing



End Sub
```

The problem is that it creates slides with a title and two entries side by side with a bullet.  I want the slide to be three lines, without the bullets.  Is there a way to do this?  I don't know how to do the layouts

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of layouts that you can use at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745137.aspx

However, only two of them match your criteria

- ppLayoutObjectOverText, and
- ppLayoutTextOverObject

Try this after your `Set activeslide` line:

```
    activeSlide.layout = ppLayoutObjectOverText
```